# how to backup buddypress messages and recipient details to another table

Tags: wordpress, hook, buddypress

How can i backup all the messages when user send messages to table "bp_messages_backup".I have tried by using some hooks but not working for me.
bp_after_message_thread_list this hook gives all the details required but insert the same message to table after refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
one can use "messages_message_after_save" Hook for to catch the message send event and then  can use

```
function insert_buddypress_message() {
  // code for inserting messages into database
}
add_action('messages_message_before_save','insert_buddypress_message');
```